# DocuSign API Embedded Signing iFrame

Tags: iframe, cookies, salesforce, docusignapi

I've created an embedded signing experience for DocuSign users using a VisualForce page.

The page renders well for users in Chrome or FF, but not in Safari.  If I enable or accept cookies from any website, it works.  However, I can't expect that all the clients have cookies enabled.  Also, the iOS Safari doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions?  Is there any workaround for using a iFrame for embedded signing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS and any other mobile interfaces that you build, DocuSign highly recommends using a `Webview` as opposed to an `iFrame`.  For instance, see the note near the top of the [Post Recipient View](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm?Highlight=webview) API call (aka Embedded Signing).

Comment: Thanks Ergin - so iFrame for Safari doesn't work unless they accept all cookies?  The webview will also resolve that issue I imagine?  Can you pass me the link to create the webview?

Comment: If you're using the DocuSign iOS SDK (which uses the Cocoa pods package manager) then see [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ios-sdk).  Otherwise you can also see the [Embedded Signing](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs) API Walkthrough which has raw Objective-C code that creates the URL, then you would just have to add the part to open in the webview.

Comment: @Ergin we're not using the SDK. we're creating the URL from an apex class and using the returned url in an iframe in the VF page and this exposed using the sites. Now this works great on browsers on desktops, but when we open the same in the iphone browsers it shows the docusign page with the contract for a split second and then gives the TTLexpired error. WOuld you know how to resolve this?

Comment: @Ergin This is what we are doing https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-SOAP-SDK/tree/master/Salesforce